# Is there a way to take a string from a .tab file to use as a variable in Nextflow?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, nextflow

As part of a pipeline I am trying to create I need to take an output from a process that is a .tab results file to use as a variable for running a series of further conditional processes in Nextflow. I can manage this in Perl with something like below, although I can't seem to add the variable to the Nextflow script:

```
my $resultsfile = 'path/to/resultsfile';
open (RESLIST, "<$resultsfile") or die$!;
my @resultlist=<RESLIST>;
$LINE = $resultlist[1];
close RESLIST or die$!; 
my @topresults = split ("\t", $LINE);
my $topidentity = $topresults[5]; 
chomp $topidentity
```

Is there a way to take the variable $topidentity to use as a variable in Nextflow or perhaps a different way to run a similar script in Nextflow to produce the same variable?

Comment: Can you show some example input? And, how are you trying to call NextFlow (or whatever that is)?

Comment: I found an [example](https://www.nextflow.io/example2.html) that uses **shell: ''' # Perl code '''**. Maybe you can try something to write in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

One groovy oneliner should do that, for example:

```
file('your-file.tab').text.readLines()[1].tokenize('\t')[5]
```

(didn't test it and quickly adapted from your perl script. it may need more adaptation)